# How to restore Copay?

Tags: copay

Installed Copay on an other iPhone, tried to restore wallet, but it does not worked. Balance is 0.00, no transaction listed. What am I doing wrong? I put in the 12 word without any error. Last I send from the amount in 2018 January.

- phrase was written in the correct order
- use all lowercase letters and no punctuation
- did you add a password to your recovery phrase? no
- Do you have the QR code or text/file backup? no

Comment: What software generated the seed phrase originally? Was it copay, or some other wallet?

Comment: It was Copay. ..

Comment: Do you have any records of address you originally deposited bitcoin into? If yes, are those addresses the same as the ones copay is now displaying to you? Or different?

Comment: I sent to GDAX, but under transfers I see only this: `Transfer ID: 4ceec2a2-d028-4086-af32-6605740431bd` not the 'real' transfer ID

Comment: You sent from Copay to GDAX? Or GDAX to copay? Do you have a working instance of the wallet (and are trying to make a second instance on a second phone)? Or do you have nothing but the seed phrase?

Comment: Sent from Copay to GDAX. Have only the seed phrase.